# regular expression to find price

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove a price from a string for a long time but I can not find a regular expression for it, anyone?

```
$txt = `<br class='clear'/> <div style='float:left;width:100px;'> 02 Dorm.<br /> A partir de: </div><div class='info' style='color:#E50000; font-weight:normal;'>
<font style='font-size:16px;'>R$ 505.726,23</font><div style='font-size:10px;line-height:10px'>*Venda sob consulta (Ref. Apto 103 Box 01)</div></div><br class=clear><br class='clear'/> <div style='float:left;width:100px;'> 03 Dorm.<br /> A partir de: </div><div class='info' style='color:#E50000; font-weight:normal;'><font style='font-size:16px;'>R$ 639.898,49</font><div style='font-size:10px;line-height:10px'>*Venda sob consulta (Ref. Apto 104 Box 02)</div></div><br class=clear><br class='clear'/><div style='float:left;width:100px;' class='normal'> Vagas:</div><div class='info' > <i class='fa fa-car'></i> &nbsp;1</div>`
```

I want only `639.898,49`

Comment: What language/environment? What did you try?

Comment: language is php I tryed this:
\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2}) but not work

Comment: What is the criteria to select `639.898,49` but not `505.726,23`?

Comment: The values ​​are of 2 and 3 bedroom homes, but I'm picking up the values ​​of having 3 bedrooms.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (using positive lookbehind) :

`(?<=R\$ ).*?(?=<\/font>)`

Comment: I have to use preg_match or preg_match_all ?

Comment: preg_match if you only want the first match. preg_match_all if you want all matches.

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern you could try is:

```
R\$ ([\d.,]+)<\/
```

The information you want is in capture **group 1**.

This pattern only takes `22 steps` to get the result. It is much more efficient than using lookbehinds.

https://regex101.com/r/4xw5ME/1